# Python3.4: Opening file with mode 'w' still gives me FileNotFound error

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I'm having a small problem: while using the function `open()` with the `'w'` mode, all documentation says that the file is created if it does not exist. Unfortunately, it appears that in my case, I get a `FileNotFound` error for some reason.

```
with open(newFileName, 'w') as newFile:
    #CODE
```

I receive the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path of file I have specified'
```

Any idea of why this might be? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: For those asking if the directory exists or not, I have made small changes to the code that might show you it is indeed the good path.

```
if not os.path.exists("example"):
    os.makedirs("example")

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

newFileName = "example/restOfPath"
newFileName = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,newFileName)

with open(newFileName, 'w') as newFile:
```

I still get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'correctPathToDirectory/example/restOfPath'
```

EDIT2: Disregard this question, problem solved. A second directory was being created after "example", thus it not working. Silly error.

Comment: could you do a `print(newFileName)` and see the file mentioned

Comment: Can you give us the value of newFileName? I suspect it may be e.g. /some/dir/filename, where /some/dir doesn't exist.

Comment: @WédneyYuri The OP is not asking to open a file in read and write mode...

Comment: I did think of that possibility so I created the directory right before that line of code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924720/filenotfounderror-errno-2, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282760/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198915/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-classa-in-python-alth

Comment: @Balaam: You _should_ get an error message if your code couldn't successfully create the new directory, but did you check that it was created ok?

Comment: Yes, the directory "example" is created.

Comment: @Balaam: What are the permissions on the directory "example"?

Comment: It gives the correct path. Disregard this question I have already fixed the problem. It seems my code was creating another directory AFTER "example" and this was the problem. Completely silly, I know. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The cause for this error might be that the directory containing your new file does not yet exist.

`open()` with `'w'` only creates the non-existing file for you but not the whole directory path. So you first need to create the directories for the file.

Comment: I did think of that possibility so I created the directory right before that line of code.

Comment: Then another possibility is that your program  has no write rights in the specified directory.

Comment: Maybe, @x-squared , but this code will run on other people's machines, I can't ask them to chmod before running the code. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Is it a directory of your choice? You can always write in the user local directories, e.g. $APPDATA in windows and $HOME/.config in Linux.

Comment: I have edited the post with more information.

Comment: There we have the problem. In case "blocks" does not exist, you create folder "example". But even if "blocks" exists, you change the file path to "example/...".

Comment: In case others like me come here looking for the code to add directory if it does not exists. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python